# Laravel API-Auth-Guard is not case-sensitive?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, api-design

i'm prototyping an API with Laravel and noticed that the API-Token is not case-sensitive when using the standard Auth-Guard for API. So api_tokens like 'CVC' and 'cvc' are treated the same.

Is that an expected behaviour? Is that ideal in regard of security? Dont think so, even with a 60-byte-string, or what do you think? And is there a way to change that?

Thanks for your thoughts!
Carsten

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be the case. Laravel attempts to [resolve the token in several ways first](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php#L76-L98)

```
 * Get the token for the current request.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTokenForRequest()
{
    $token = $this->request->query($this->inputKey);
    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->input($this->inputKey);
    }
    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->bearerToken();
    }
    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->getPassword();
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Where that method is invoked when [attempting to resolve an instance of the user](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php#L54-L71):

```
/**
 * Get the currently authenticated user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function user()
{
    // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
    // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
    // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
    if (! is_null($this->user)) {
        return $this->user;
    }
    $user = null;
    $token = $this->getTokenForRequest();
    if (! empty($token)) {
        $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials(
            [$this->storageKey => $token]
        );
    }
    return $this->user = $user;
}
```

And the `provider` in this case is the `DatabaseUserProvider`, which the method `retrieveByCredentials` [performs a strict case-sensitive check](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php#L99-L118) using the Database Factories `->where()` method, no **like** is used, you can see that here:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
    // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
    // generic "user" object that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
    $query = $this->conn->table($this->table);
    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }
    // Now we are ready to execute the query to see if we have an user matching
    // the given credentials. If not, we will just return nulls and indicate
    // that there are no matching users for these given credential arrays.
    $user = $query->first();
    return $this->getGenericUser($user);
}
```

So no, your case is not typical, and likely there are other components in play here that we're not privy to.

Comment: Ok, i'll have a deeper look. But as im said i am developing on a fresh laravel install. Nothing special except that it is my dev-mac.

I'll check my script on a vagrant-installation to verify if my mac is the underlying problem.

Thanks for your Response!